# Android Flavor ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER

Tags: android, build, live-wallpaper, variant, android-productflavors

Hi I'm trying to implement android app flavor (free and full) to live wallpaper. In eclipse, I used to use this following code to open live wallpaper preview from my own android Activity:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
        String pkg = WallpaperService.class.getPackage()
                .getName();
        String cls = WallpaperService.class.getCanonicalName();
        intent.putExtra(
                WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
```

But now it does not work correctly as the free and full flavor are using same package name with just different applicationId in android studio. The problem is when it starts either in free or full version, it will goto full version no matter how, regardless of what flavor it is. I specify app flavor using applicationId in project gradle like this:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.kkl.app.free"
    }
    full {
        applicationId "com.kkl.app"
    }
}
```

How do we make it to get the correct package name that matches the app flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getPackageName()` in your `Activity` to get Android packageName. This will be packageName from manifest file i.e. the one equal to current applicationId.

Method documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29).

Comment: You're right! Using getPackageName() for pkg string value works perfectly. But strangely, the cls value should always remain like this: "com.kkl.app,WallpaperService" instead of "com.kkl.app,free.WallpaperService". Seems like android flavor just changes package name, but not the directory of the physical file like Eclipse. Thanks alot for ur help.

Comment: @kkl yes, that's exactly how it works. Nothing strange. That's why they changed the name into applicationId instead of packageName - to avoid misunderstanding across Java programmers. And into Intent you pass component name not the path to source file.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using the following:

```
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
        String pkg = getPackageName();
        String cls = WallpaperService.class.getCanonicalName();
        intent.putExtra(
                WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
```

Special thank to Lingviston

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with flavors, but what you are trying to do is far simpler than anyone has answered.

First you have a build variant to select your flavor for debugging and running. So use this, otherwise all your debugging will use default main release.

Secondly, you don't have to get package name, just use a build config flag or check flavor. I.E.

```
    android {
    signingConfigs {
        releaseA35Demo {
            storeFile file("$projectDir/../yaskeystore.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv('YOUR_APP_STUDIO_STORE_PASSWORD')
            keyAlias System.getenv('YOUR_APP_STUDIO_KEY_ALIAS')
            keyPassword System.getenv('YOUR_APP_STUDIO_KEY_PASSWORD')
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'default'

    productFlavors {
        a35Demo {
            dimension 'default'
            applicationId "com.appstudio35.yourappstudio"
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://fakeNumbers.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3006"'
            buildConfigField "int", "BUSINESS_ID", "1"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.01.01-b1"
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        a35DemoDev {
            dimension 'default'
            applicationId "com.appstudio35.yourappstudio.dev"
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://fakeNumbers2.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3006"'
            buildConfigField "int", "BUSINESS_ID", "2"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.01.01-b1"
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            productFlavors.a35Demo.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseA35Demo
            productFlavors.a35DemoDev.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseA35Demo
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply reference it in code like:

```
BuildConfig.BUSINESS_ID
```

Wherever you need it. Just make sure you don't accidentally use the BuildConfig of a library project when it auto imports the BuildConfig.

Next way is if you want to check your flavor you can simply do
BuildConfig.FLAVOR to see which one you are on. However, keep in mind there are some compiler warnings about using it because you are checking against a flavor and the BuildConfig assumes it will ALWAYS be whatever you are currently in for the Build Variant dropdown, Which is not true, you can ignore this always true or always false warning, I assure you it works.

Lastly your package issue is just because you are debugging the wrong build variant. I'll add an image so you can see where to change that.

[image]

Hope that helps.